# Function executed without being called

Tags: ruby

I have a function `func`, and it executes automatically; I have never called it.

```
BEGIN {
  print "Start"
}
*data = gets;
test = true
for i in 0...data.length
  if i==0
    print data[i]
  end
  if i==0 and !test
    print "test"
  else
    print "uu"
  end
end
END {
  print "End"
}

def func()
  print "test1"
  yield
  print "test2"
end

func {
  print "func block"
}
```

Output of above code:

```
StartUSERINPUT
USERINPUT
uutest1func blocktest2End
```

I don't want that function to be executed by itself but only when I call it. I can't use a function with parameters due to this automatic calling.

Comment: Huh? You call `func` right after defining it, directly on the next line.

Comment: Hey I am new to ruby and I am in a learning stage, so you don't have to be rude, I didn't know that by making a func block would call the function, I thought it can be called only using func() and not by func{}.

Comment: I assumed you knew that parentheses were optional because you actually call `gets` without parentheses on line 4, `length`  without parentheses on line 6, and `print` without parentheses on lines 2, 8, 11, 13, 17, 21, 23, and 27. So, you use calls without parentheses 11 times and expect it to be a call 10 times and not a call 1 time, that's what confused me.

Comment: Have no idea why people vote this question down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func {}` is actually calling the function `func`.

Why? `{}` is for accepting block. You can think of blocks as arguments.

See how the BEGIN and END works.

They got called with the parameters passed in (via blocks).

Comment: Ok I get it now, didn't know that func block actually calls the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve, but this:

```
func {
  print "func block"
}
```

in Ruby is a function call, exactly like this:

```
func() {
  print "func block"
}
```